# Ubuntu : mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, ubuntu

> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP
>   configuration.

I tried almost everything but all in vain. I already enabled extension from *php.ini* file, installed every available extension available for PHP but it's not working. I'm using *Ubuntu* on **AWS**.

Comment: Which `php.ini` file?

Comment: The solution to this problem is to install the extension and enable it in PHP. If you have tried that and it did not work then run `phpinfo()` under the environment you need to run PHP and make sure that mbstring is installed. If not then there's a good chance you have multiple PHP installations or setups and are not changing all of them